# update mysql database with form php $stmt

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with updating my MySQL database with form inputs. I believe its an issue with the ID or something, but I am unsure.

Here is the full document:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION["message"] = '<p class="message">Client updated successfully!</div>';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ssl";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact Manager - Client Directory</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/custom/css/main.css">
<link type="image/ico" rel="icon" href="assets/custom/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
     <div class="header">
       <div class="logo">
    <h1>Contact Manager</h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="clientdirectory.php"><li>Client Directory</li></a>
      <a href="admin.php"><li>Admin</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div> <!-- header div -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="inner-header">
      <h2>Control Panel > Update Clients</h2>
      <?php
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('select id, firstname, lastname, username, password, email, phone from users');
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
          echo '<div class="employee-inner">';
          echo '<div class="employee">';
          echo '<h3>ID</h3>' . '<p>' . $row['id'] . '</p>';
          echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="updateclients.php" method="POST">';
          echo '<input class="update" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder=' . $row['firstname'] . ' required />';
          echo "<br />";
          echo '<input class="update" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder=' . $row['lastname'] . ' required />';
          echo "<br />";
          echo '<input class="update" type="text" name="username" placeholder=' . $row['username'] . ' required />';
          echo "<br />";
          echo "<input class='update' type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' required />";
          echo "<br />";
          echo '<input class="update" type="text" name="email" placeholder=' . $row['email'] . ' required />';
          echo "<br />";
          echo '<input class="update" type="text" name="phone" placeholder=' . $row['phone'] . ' required />';
          echo "<br />";
          echo '<input class="update-submit" type="submit" name="update" value="Update Client" />';
          echo '</form>';
          echo '<a href="deleteclients.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><button>Delete Client</button></a>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
          $employeeid = $_GET['id'];
          $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
          $lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
          $username = $_GET['username'];
          $password = $_GET['password'];
          $email = $_GET['email'];
          $phone = $_GET['phone'];
          $encrypted = md5("encrypted".$password);
          $stmt = $dbh->prepare("update users set firstname='" . $firstname . "', lastname='" . $lastname . "', username='" . $username . "'. password='" . $password . "', email='" . $email . "', phone='" . $phone . "' values (:firstname, :lastname, :username, :encrypted, :email, :phone);");
          $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
          $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
          $stmt->bindParam(':encrypted', $encrypted);
          $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
          $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
          $stmt->execute();
          echo '<p class="message">Client updated successfully!</p>';
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy 2016 Content Manager. All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer
</div> <!-- content div -->
</div> <!-- container div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any information will help. Thanks and I appreciate it. There are no PHP errors, but it doesn't update the database.

Comment: *I'm having issues*... what issues? Are you getting any error messages? What is the desired behaviour and what exactly is happening?

Comment: There are no syntax or displayed php errors, but when the form is submitted it doesn't update the database with entered information.

Comment: Try dumping your super globals.  You are confusing GET and POST and form placeholders with values.

Comment: post form method and get arrays; won't work and will sometimes fail silently.

Comment: Plus, your UPDATE syntax is incorrect and believe you are not checking for errors via php and the query. Had you been, you would have been signaled about it.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with something weak like MD5**.

Comment: That is not how binding works. The values dont go in the query, placeholders do. Also your `&copy` is missing the closing semi-colon, some browsers might auto correct that but entities should be `&NAME;`. Also your `update` should have a `where` clause or you'll be updating every record.

Comment: You're mixing up `INSERT` and `UPDATE` syntax. Then you're using variable concatenation for the `UPDATE` part, but `:placeholder` for the `INSERT` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bits of both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` syntax in your statement. It should just be:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("update users set firstname=:firstname, lastname=:lastname, username=:username, password=:password, email=:email, phone=:phone
                        where id = :id");
```

You need to bind an additional parameter:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

Another problem is that your form uses `method="POST"`. That means all the parameters will be in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`, so change all those variables.

Comment: I've corrected this but the form still doesn't update the database. Am I doing something wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Your form has `method="POST"`, but you're using `$_GET` for all the inputs. Change that to `$_POST`.

Comment: I'm getting Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\Week 4\Contact Manager\updateclients.php on line 77

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\Week 4\Contact Manager\updateclients.php on line 93

Comment: I know that ID isn't in the form. I'm confused as to what to do.

Comment: Add it as a hidden input: `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>`

Comment: I appreciate it, that worked :) still one last error: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\Week 4\Contact Manager\updateclients.php on line 95

Comment: Found out why, got it. Thanks for your help Barmar.